# filter_horizontal does not work when using formfield_for_manytomany

Tags: django, django-admin

I can get filter_horizontal to work, but as soon as I add a formfield_for_manytomany it stops working. Is there any way to use formfield_for_manytomany and maintain the filter_horizontal?

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    filter_horizontal = ('users',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'users':
            kwargs["queryset"] = User.objects.filter(profile__api_user=True)

        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`formfield_for_manytomany` and `filter_horizontal` should work fine together.

The problem is that you are calling the wrong method when you call `super()`. It should be

```
return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```